# how to create json files from 3 php arrays

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have 3 arrays in php and i want to create for each value a json file:

```
$aa = array('jack', 'joe', 'john');
$bb = array('audi', 'bmw', 'mercedes');
$cc = array('red', 'blue', 'gray');

foreach($aa as $a) {
    $data['name'] = $a;
    foreach($bb as $b) {
        $data['car'] = $b;
    }
    foreach($cc as $c) {
        $data['color'] = $c;
    }
    
    $data_file = 'data/'.$a.'.json'; // jack.json and joe.json and john.json
    $json_data = json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    file_put_contents($data_file,$json_data);
    
}
```

My json files should look like this:

jack.json

```
{
  "name": "jack",
  "car": "audi",
  "color": "red"
}
```

joe.json

```
{
  "name": "joe",
  "car": "bmw",
  "color": "blue"
}
```

john.json

```
{
  "name": "john",
  "car": "mercedes",
  "color": "gray"
}
```

I do not succeed in it with the code above: fields **car** and **color** stay empty in each json file...

Comment: Not reproducible - demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/87ebb26e636fe57214e7a4083291e12e82d60ad4 ...although the logic is still wrong, since you get "gray" and "mercedes" for all of them due to the inner loops. But those fields certainly aren't empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your looping logic doesn't make that much sense.

You're looping over array `$aa`, and in that loop, you'll loop over each `$bb` and `$cc`.

---

Instead, since all 3 arrays have the same length and so index, we can use 1 single loop, get the key, and call all 3 array's with that key:

```php
<?php

$aa = array('jack', 'joe', 'john');
$bb = array('audi', 'bmw', 'mercedes');
$cc = array('red', 'blue', 'gray');

foreach($aa as $k => $a) {

    $data = [];
    $data['name'] = $aa[$k];
    $data['car'] = $bb[$k];
    $data['color'] = $cc[$k];
    
    $data_file = 'data/' . $aa[$k] . '.json'; // (jack.json or joe.json or john.json)
    $json_data = json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    
    echo 'Writing to: ' . $data_file . PHP_EOL;
    var_dump($json_data);
}
```

Will output:

```
Writing to: data/jack.json
string(61) "{
    "name": "jack",
    "car": "audi",
    "color": "red"
}"
Writing to: data/joe.json
string(60) "{
    "name": "joe",
    "car": "bmw",
    "color": "blue"
}"
Writing to: data/john.json
string(66) "{
    "name": "john",
    "car": "mercedes",
    "color": "gray"
}"
```

Using `var_dump` instead off `file_put_contents` for demo purposes

---

### [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVBNb4MwDL3nV/iAFJCqch/rdkBI7T5o1TFNE6qQCWmBFoLSsmna9ttZEjql03Kxn9@z/eKu7Ibh@rYrO0IcRJgBSokfLq2R7ekEaC34GMqWegFx8txqsC8qTebNuw4Nl4wX/Gh0jFmd5IWRHXoza6eKWkO2QnJkpasX4xGcPcxuwEEPPgkB9ZwCT9pSugksTmmLDacbVVd9qbP/SzKUI5fn/zlxEGeWMctaSbatDlzRVAOfwvR3hcrotD6Klgbg@@Dq6xgMQoI60UVetgZ441SdZudvmJy3TBTcNesmcPe0jLP4@TFaL8IsnEfhPXyNxdU6SpJXFRZx4l345KwUQF9kdaraHZzEFRib1v0UVvNVFi0fxqY3lFnRN51rrahx32QYfgA)

Comment: Agreed this is more logical, although the OP's original code doesn't appear to produce the fault they are reporting (but it does contain a different logical flaw, which is corrected by this code).